# Build.cs not working even after being restores to it's previous version

Tags: c#, unreal-engine4

I'm trying to compile a project I'm working on and this error mesages pops out:

```
Invalidating makefile for SpaceShooterEditor (SpaceShooter.Build.cs modified)
While compiling E:\ue projects\SpaceShooter\Intermediate\Build\BuildRules\SpaceShooterModuleRules.dll:
e:\ue projects\SpaceShooter\Source\SpaceShooter\SpaceShooter.Build.cs(3,29) : error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ModuleRules' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
e:\ue projects\SpaceShooter\Source\SpaceShooter\SpaceShooter.Build.cs(5,25) : error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ReadOnlyTargetRules' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
ERROR: Unable to compile source files.
```

Any idea why this might happen? Last night i was trying to code a widget, modified the build.cs, then replaced the modified version (which chrashed the game) with a build.cs that worked previously, and still nothing? Is there any hope to make it work or should i start over? Moreover, how can this be avoided?

I already did the restarts and refreshes. I went to even delete the binaries and some cashed files and it didn't work.

Below you'll find the content of the Build.cs:

```cs
public class SpaceShooter : ModuleRules
{
    public SpaceShooter(ReadOnlyTargetRules Target) : base(Target)
    {
        PCHUsage = PCHUsageMode.UseExplicitOrSharedPCHs;

        PublicDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[] { "Core", "CoreUObject", "Engine", "InputCore" });

        PrivateDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[] { });

        // Uncomment if you are using Slate UI
        // PrivateDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[] { "Slate", "SlateCore" });

        // Uncomment if you are using online features
        // PrivateDependencyModuleNames.Add("OnlineSubsystem");

        // To include OnlineSubsystemSteam, add it to the plugins section in your uproject file with the Enabled attribute set to true
    }
}
```

When i try to input specify the `using UnrealBuildTool;`, Visual Studio, for some reason, deletes it when i hit compile or save.

Comment: Did it come with a different error when you replaced the file with a previous version?

Comment: Unfotunatelly, no. Same error. I'll post the content of said build file soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some digging, i found out that wrapping the content in a `namespace UnrealBuidTool.Rules{}` solves this. In the end, the build file looks like this:

```
namespace UnrealBuildTool.Rules
{
    public class SpaceShooter : ModuleRules
    {
        public SpaceShooter(ReadOnlyTargetRules Target) : base(Target)
        {
            PCHUsage = PCHUsageMode.UseExplicitOrSharedPCHs;

            PublicDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[] { "Core", "CoreUObject", "Engine", "InputCore" });

            PrivateDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[] { });

            // Uncomment if you are using Slate UI
            // PrivateDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[] { "Slate", "SlateCore" });

            // Uncomment if you are using online features
            // PrivateDependencyModuleNames.Add("OnlineSubsystem");

            // To include OnlineSubsystemSteam, add it to the plugins section in your uproject file with the Enabled attribute set to true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah that's really something you would overlook, nice that you figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

As you do not share what is included in your Build.cs file I will just explain what the error is and how you could fix it. The error basically says that it couldn't compile the Build.cs file based on the lines 29 and 25, and that the types that are used there called 'ModuleRules' and 'ReadOnlyTargetRules' could not be found in any of the namespaces that were included by the using statements at the top of Build.cs. These types are both stored in the UnrealBuildTool namespace and can thus be included in your file by typing:

```
using UnrealBuildTool;
```

This however seems like a trivial solution to your problem, but as you do not share a lot of info this is the best solution I can give you for now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I updated my question to show the contents of build.cs